# PHP Regular Expression extracting HTML Links

Tags: php, html, regex, hyperlink, extract

I've been spending all morning trying to figure this out but nothing's working.

Basically what I'm trying to do is take a website, and extract *one link in particular* from the page. Basically the website is a forum and at the very bottom of the page is a section that says "The newest member is *MEMBERNAMEHERE*)". The member name is a link, directed at their user profile. I'm able to get links off the page but it doesn't seem to go that far when I set the regex to take EVERY link off the page. The code I have:

```
$url = "[The forum's url goes here.]";
$input = file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
$regexp = "The newest member is <a.*href=\"(.*?)\".*?\>(.*)\<\/a\>+/)";
preg_match_all("The newest member is /\<a.*href=\"(.*?)\".*?\>(.*)\<\/a\>+/)", $input, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo($match[0][2]);
```

What I'm trying to match in the document is

```
The newest member is <a href="http://forumurl.com/profile/usernumber">MEMBERNAME</a>)
```

I need to pull MEMBERNAME out of the script above. The url is almost at the very bottom of the page, so I'm wondering if that could by why it isn't working properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you use a HTML parser, you won't need to care at all. It will just do it. Why do you need to re-invent the wheel? - And actually as long as you don't give the particular `$url`, well, nobody is able to tell how it is done.

Comment: You would probably appreciate the help you get from raising `error_reporting`.

Comment: if I got $1 for every time someone asks how to parse HTML with regex I'd be rich ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code would instead be:

```
$url = "[The forum's url goes here.]";
$input = file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
$regexp = "/The newest member is \<a.*href=\"(.*?)\".*?\>(.*)\<\/a\>\)/";
preg_match_all($regexp, $input, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo($match[0][2]);
```

This successfully echoes: "MEMBERNAME".

However you need to be careful that there isn't more than one of the same case, or if you are doing this across multiple forums, you need to make sure that this is consistent. Otherwise you could include more code at the beginning or end of the regex function.

You can use this [Regular Expression Test Tool](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php) to help you out and perhaps learn more about how Regex works.

Comment: Still returns nothing. That's why I'm wondering if the links position on the page is causing issues. It doesn't appear to be picking up the link at all.  EDIT: That can't be the case.. the entire page source with that expression work fine in the Regular Expression Test Tool.

Comment: Try the updated version, perhaps you hadn't defined the $regexp variable.

Comment: Oh right okay sorry, for some reason in the test tool it's the opposite.